# least squares: verify simple derivative

Tags: calculus, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

What is the derivative of $||Y-X\beta||_2$ w.r.t $X$?

I have $(Y-X\beta)^T(Y-X \beta) = Y^TY-Y^TX \beta-\beta^TX^TY+\beta^TX^TX\beta$ which gives the derivative as $-Y\beta^T -Y\beta^T +2X\beta\beta^T$

Is this correct? If not, what is the correct result?

Comment: If $Y$ is a vector, $X$ is a matrix, and $\beta$ is a vector, then $$\|Y-X\beta\|_2^2 = (Y-X\beta)^T(Y-X \beta).$$ You are taking derivative of the square of the Euclidean norm.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao Thats right, but is my result for the derivative correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao Thanks for verifying!